# Algorithm for codechef :Adding Fraction

Tags: algorithm

I am working on problem Adding Fraction: http://www.codechef.com/problems/ADDFRAC/
at codechef.
If someone can help me in understanding algorithm for problem it would be great help.

P.S :I tried this problem but since my algo is O(n^2) i am getting Time Limit Exceeded.
My code: http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/2278117

Comment: How do you interpret "continuous fractions" in the problem statement?  Do you think they actually meant "contiguous"?

Comment: it meant contiguous sum of fraction using their rule of adding starting from index "i" to any index less than < size of array

Comment: @VaughnCato: Yes they meant continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it in two simple for loops.

Whereas what you should do is start in the reverse fashion and keep computing till the sum is greater then the current sum

If you see the top answer you can see that the index is taken from n-1 to 1

The computing goes on till the if condition is met - that is the next fraction addition is greater than the current sum

It stores this in a separate array upto (to indicate the maximum index till which this holds true)

```
for(int index=n-1; index>0; index--) {  
 int j=index+1;
 while(j<=n) {
  next_num=numerator[j];
  next_den=denominator[j];
  if((1.0*numerator[index])/denominator[index]
      <(1.0*(numerator[index]+next_num))
     /(denominator[index]+next_den)) {
         numerator[index]=numerator[index]+next_num;
         denominator[index]=denominator[index]+next_den;
         j=upto[j]+1;
//printf("%d/%d ", numerator[index], denominator[index]);
} else {
  upto[index]=j-1;
  break;
  }
}
 if(j>n) {
  upto[index]=n;
 }
}
```

Comment: Yeah u are right,anyways i already implemented that algo. and got accepted.Thnx.